# What is the plural of 'sorry'?

Tags: meaning, grammatical-number

One apology   --> many apologies.

One good deed --> many good deeds.

One sorry     --> many **_**  ?

Comment: Can you give a grammatical sentence which uses "one sorry"?

Comment: In drunkMonk's defense: He probably had something like "A simple 'sorry' would have prevented the situation from escalating". But the 'sorry' here is a quote of what you were expected to say, not a noun.

Comment: Simple: I'm sorry. 

Reminds me of a Bible verse: “... how many times shall I forgive my brother when he sins against me? Up to seven times?” Jesus answered, “I tell you, not seven times, but seventy-seven times.”

Comment: @Justin: Matthew 18:22 (either seventy-seven or seventy times seven)

Comment: @JustinJenkins *I'm sorry* doesn't use *sorry* as a noun. One could not say *I am one sorry* (one could say *I am one sorry fool*, but then *sorry* is, again, an adjective)

Comment: The main question is can we use 'sorry' as a noun referring to the act of apologizing or expressing regret; here are some [examples](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sorries%2Csorrys&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) from books.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[James Leigh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Henry_Leigh_Hunt) in his "Sir Ralph Esher", 1832 [wrote](http://books.google.com/books?id=gbMLAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA271&dq=%22sorrys%22&hl=en&ei=tWzLToXVMMOK4gThhcke&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22sorrys%22&f=false)

> "Sorry me no **sorrys**, my Lord Duke," cried the Duchess

(I have a feeling that this is slang employed literary, so it is not necessarily grammatical use)

Junʼichirō Tanizaki in his "A cat, a man, and two women: stories" gets translated [into](http://books.google.com/books?id=gNxBAQAAIAAJ&q=%22sorrys%22&dq=%22sorrys%22&hl=en&ei=G2zLTqXuBMb24QTC_chT&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBDgo)

> Then, with twenty or so thank-yous and awfully-**sorrys**, he went on to ask for the loan of a lamp for his bicycle...

Wordnik lists [sorries](http://www.wordnik.com/words/sorries) as a word, but it is the only one (next to urban dictionary, see [onelook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=sorries&ls=a)) though these two sources are not enough to consider a word grammatical. No dictionary lists *sorrys*.

The word is definitively used in spoken language (most [examples](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sorries,sorrys&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) analyzed are such examples). It refers to the multiple acts of apologizing, making a noun out of the adjective, according to following logic:

> Your sorry = Your apology
>   Your apologies = Your *sorries/sorrys*

The spelling is not a problem in spoken language, but in writing it is. I suggest to quote the word to indicate unusual usage.

Comment: I think this is a very good example of artistically breaking the grammatical rules to create a vivid picture of the scene the author wants to describe.

Answer (score 10):

"sorry" is an adjective, so there is no plural form.